# Android Studio Iguana: XML-Code line indents one character to the left by clicking

Tags: android, android-studio, xml-formatting

I'm using Android Studio Iguana.
My problem is, that if I click on a tag-element this element indents to the left and the opening tag "<" is at the same height as the first letter of the tag name.

View without clicking:
[<Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWJKr.png)

View when clicking:
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dAcx.png)

Also there is another problem maybe correlating to the above one:
There is the error "The resource name shouldn't be empty", but it isn't:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wek1c.png)